# Что такое Y-комбинатор

Tags: функции, математика

Кто-нибудь может на пальцах объяснить что такое y-комбинатор в λ-исчислении?

Comment: Наверное он еще сможет объяснить, что такое монада в двух словах...

Comment: Для вопросов касательно чисто математики есть сайт https://math.stackexchange.com/ того же сообщества. Он правда на английском. Здесь форум программистов. Врядли кого интерисует здесь тема комбинаторов.

Comment: Понять монады так же просто, как бросить курить. Я делал это много раз.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Комбинатор - это элементарная функция высшего порядка. "Элементарная" означает что эта функция предназначена для того чтобы строить на ее основе другие функции; в некоторых системах аксиом комбинаторы считаются неделимыми.

"Высшего порядка" означает что функция принимает или возвращает не скалярное значение, а другую функцию.

Неподвижная точка - это термин из матанализа, он означает такую точку x<sub>0</sub> что f(x<sub>0</sub>) = x<sub>0</sub> (у каждой функции свои неподвижные точки).

Таким образом, комбинатор неподвижной точки - это элементарная функция высшего порядка, которая ищет для указанной функции ее неподвижную точку.

---

С точки зрения математики, поиск неподвижной точки - это решение уравнения, довольно сложная задача. Но все меняется когда неподвижная точка ищется не у обычной функции, а у функции высшего порядка.

И так, допустим у нас есть функция f, и у нее есть неподвижная точка x:

```
f x = x
```

По определению, комбинатор неподвижной точки должен для любого f найти x:

```
Y f = x
```

Подставив второе уравнение в первое, получим

```
f (Y f) = Y f
```

Или, что то же самое,

```
Y f = f (Y f) = f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f ...))))))))
```

Это равенство верно для любого комбинатора неподвижной точки, но для комбинатора Y это не просто равенство, но еще и алгоритм: он именно так и работает. Разумеется, подобная бесконечная рекурсия возможно только в "ленивых" вариантах λ-исчисления.

---

Для чего используется этот комбинатор? Он используется для того чтобы писать рекурсивные функции в тех языках где нет другого способа это сделать.

Рассмотрим, к примеру, одну из возможных записей факториала:

```
fac n = if (n = 0) 1 (n * fac (n-1))
```

Если язык запрещает делать прямой рекурсивный вызов (обращаться к fac изнутри определения fac) - можно использовать комбинатор неподвижной точки:

```
fac = Y (λf . λn . if (n = 0) 1 (n * f (n-1)))
```

На практике так почти никто не пишет, потому что во всех нормальных языках рекурсия разрешена.

В теории же комбинатор неподвижной точки - это стандартная реализация рекурсивных вызовов.

Comment: А что такое "порядок функции" в комбинаторной логике?

Answer (score 2):

По определению, комбинатор, который переводит свой аргумент в его неподвижную точку:

```
∀f . f(Y f) ≡ Y f
```

В лямбда-исчислении есть простая его форма для лямбда-выражений:

```
Y = λf . (λx . f(x x)) (λx . f(x x))
```

В частности, если начать проводить экспансию, то

```
Yf
= (λf . (λx . f(x x)) (λx . f(x x))) f
= (λx . f(x x)) (λx . f(x x))
= f(x x)|x = (λx . f(x x))
= f((λx . f(x x)) (λx . f(x x)))
= f((λf . (λx . f(x x)) (λx . f(x x))) f)
= f(Yf)
```

Примерно на пальцах...