# Вопрос по алгоритму вычисления кратного факториала

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

С задачей возникли трудности. Не понимаю, как выглядит ход решения, нужны идеи куда копать. Как вычислять факториал- знаю. Уверен, то кратный вычисляется похожим образом, но в чем различия? Буду признателен, если сможете объяснить на пальцах как найти кратный факториал, я тут начал решать, но запутался.
[тут вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#.D0.9A.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BB)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def Kfactorial(n, k = 1):
    if n in [0,1]:
        return 1

    res = 1

    for i in range(1, n+1, k):
        res *= i

    return res

n = 8
#k = 3

Kfactorial(n, k)
```

Comment: [Вот тут](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1112017/kratnyy-faktorial-nekotorye-momenty) есть по теме для С++. Если поможет, пожалуйста оформите как авторский ответ (ответ на собственный вопрос) сюда

Comment: @Fisherman , да, я видел эту ссылку. Но там без пояснений и ниего не понятно.

Comment: Считайте факториал с хвоста последовательности. `range(n, 0, -k)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прямой ход

```
def KfacF(n, k = 1):
    res = 1
    r = n%k if n%k > 0 else k
    while r <= n:
        res *= r
        r += k
    return res
```

Обратный ход короче:

```
def Kfac(n, k = 1):
    res = 1
    while n > 0:
        res *= n
        n -= k
    return res
```

Рекурсивный метод ещё короче:

```
def KfacR(n, k = 1):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return n * KfacR(n-k, k)
```

Или однострочно, как @mkkik предложил в комментариях:

```
return 1 if n < 2 else n * KfacR(n - k, k)
```

---

```
print(Kfac(8,3))   >>> 80 = 8 * 5 * 2
print(Kfac(6,3))   >>> 18 = 6 * 3
```

Comment: Для рекурсии: `return 1 if n < 2 else n * KfacR(n - k, k)`, чтобы избавиться от multiple return.

Comment: @ mkkik выглядит очень круто. Этот уровень сложности пока не доступен мне(

Comment: @MBo, спасибо за ответ и примеры разных решений с обратным ходом- для меня нагляднее, а вывод после рекурсии- позволил разобраться окончательно.
Как я понял обратный ход проще- т.к не надо искать первый член последовательности, как при прямом ходе. В обратном он получается просто вычитанием n-k, в прямом же первый член должен подходить к условию r = n%k if n%k > 0 else k

Answer (score 1):

Исключительно для **теоретического интереса** (не для применения в рабочем коде) можно упомянуть возможность использования в `python` функций высшего порядка, в том числе анонимных.

Задача вычисления факториала рекурсивным методом может быть решена с помощью [Y-комбинатора](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator) (материалы: [Рекурсия с помощью Y–комбинатора (python)](https://habr.com/post/50354/), [Что такое Y-комбинатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819026)).

В коде ниже вызов комбинатора намеренно выполняется внутри `print`, чтобы показать возможность не прибегать к созданию имен функций.

```
print(

    # тело комбинатора
    (
         lambda n, k: (lambda f, *args: f(f, *args)) 
        (lambda f, n, k: 1 if n < 2 else n * f(f, n - k, k), n, k)
    )

    # аргументы, передаваемые в комбинатор
    (5, 2)
)  # -> 15
```

Comment: лямбда функции выглядит круто и непонятно, я до них еще доберусь, а пока эта часть для изучения. Но на всякий случай поставил +.